# Python: Is it possible to colour boxplot points according to a scale, not used for the boxplot itself?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I would like to get something like the picture I attach using python:
A boxplot graph for variable X1 data (divided into 2 clusters, and would like to colour each point in the clusters according to another variable (variable z in this case).
I don't need the script on how to do such a thing... just to know if it is posible using either seaborn, matplotlib, etc. I could not find an answer to my question in stackoverflow.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: you want to do a boxplot and overlay a swarm plot. The seaborn docs have examples of this.

Comment: Thank you @PaulH! sorry for the basic question, i'm new with python!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/), you can plot a [`stripplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html) or a [`swarmplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html) on top of a [`boxplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()
N = 200
df = pd.DataFrame({'X1': np.random.normal(10, 10, N),
                   'Cluster': np.random.randint(1, 3, N),
                   'Z': np.random.uniform(1, 10, N)})
df['X1'] = df['X1'] + 10 * df['Cluster']
ax = sns.boxplot(data=df, x='Cluster', y='X1', color='dodgerblue', showfliers=False)
# sns.swarmplot(data=df, x='Cluster', y='X1', hue='Z', palette='Reds', ax=ax)
sns.stripplot(data=df, x='Cluster', y='X1', hue='Z', palette='Reds', ax=ax)
ax.legend_.remove()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]